# Finding duplicate subarrays inside a multi dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm saving images in a multi dimenisonal `numpy` array `a` in shape `(100,128,128,1)`. I'd like to check whether there are duplicate images in array `a`. Other than some for loops implementation, what would be the pythonic way to do it?

Comment: You gotta explain more about the input data.

Comment: Maybe `from itertools import permutations` is a solution?

Comment: @Divakar Images are in `(128,128,1)` size and there are `100` images in the array `a`. I'd like to see whether there are duplicate images in entire `a`.

Comment: And if there are duplicate images in array a, what's the expected output?

Comment: @Divakar returning duplicate indexes in a tuple would be plausible.

Comment: Think you should look into `np.unique( ..axis, return_index=True)`. Check out `return_inverse` argument too.

Comment: @Divakar this will do it thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, we need `np.unique`, but some extra steps are needed to gather duplicate indices. Here's the complete implementation that gather duplicate images in one tuple each, while non-duplicate ones would end up alone in a tuple each -

```
def gather_duplicate_indices(a):
    _,tags,count = np.unique(a, axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
    sidx = tags.argsort()
    return np.split(sidx, count.cumsum())[:-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [43]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(10,2,2,1))
    ...: a[5] = a[2]
    ...: a[7] = a[2]
    ...: a[6] = a[1]
    ...: a[9] = a[4]
# so the pairings are (2, 5, 7), (1, 6), (4, 9), while rest are singles.

In [44]: gather_duplicate_indices(a)
Out[44]: 
[array([4, 9]),
 array([8]),
 array([3]),
 array([1, 6]),
 array([2, 5, 7]),
 array([0])]
```